# HTML button moves down in body if text is too long inside the button

Tags: html, css, button

The best way to know what I'm referring to is to see the output of the code on a screen larger than 900px wide. Making the big text shorter is not an option.

I also really want to avoid making the button any larger in either direction.
If anything, I would like the button to be a little smaller, as far as height goes.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 440px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.info {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This sentence is too long and it brings it down.</div>
        <div class="info">I can't figure it out, please help.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
</body>
```

Comment: What you want you cannot fit that big font in 900px box? do you want it to just be clipped?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava If you make the example code's window beyond 900px, such that the body extended on a 1080p monitor, it will show my issue. No matter how large I make the buttons' height, it will still show the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you two solutions. Using `flex` and `position: absolute`.

This is a `flex` solution. You need to wrap buttons in an additional `div`, assigning `flex` rules to this `div`. Like these ones:

```
.btn_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

.btn_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 440px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.info {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="btn_container">
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This sentence is too long and it brings it down.</div>
        <div class="info">I can't figure it out, please help.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
   </div>
</body>
```

And this is an `position: absolute` solution. I noticed all the edits in the `css`.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 440px;
  height: 140px;
  /*padding: 20px;*/ /* remove it */
  position: relative; /* add it */
}

.title {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute; /* add it */
  top: 0; /* add it */
  left: 0; /* add it */
  right: 0; /* add it */
  padding: 15px; /* add it */
}

.info {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute; /* add it */
  left: 0; /* add it */
  right: 0; /* add it */
  bottom: 0; /* add it */
  padding: 15px; /* add it */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This sentence is too long and it brings it down.</div>
        <div class="info">I can't figure it out, please help.</div>
    </button>
  <button>
        <div class="title">This test is short.</div>
        <div class="info">And there is no problem here.</div>
    </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `float:left` to your button.

```
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 440px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 20px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px; /* to add some space */
}
```

The float property in CSS is used for positioning and layout on web pages.
[Read more about float in this article.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/)